# Approximation of an unitary operator by simple operators

Tags: quantum-information

For quantum computation, it's well known that any unitary operator can be approximated with an arbitrary accuracy by simple operators, for example to approximate an unitary operator on n qubits by no more than $e^n$ universal gates.

What's puzzling me is that: Can we decompose an unitary operator into no more than $e^n$ (or with a similar complexity) simple unitary operators, i.e., as a tensor product of simple unitary operators? Here I am not talking about 'approximation' but a precise 'decomposition'. Also the simple operators need not to be from a finite set as in the universal gate case, we can use any simple operators (for example any 2-level unitary operator).

So I want to have $U=U_1U_2....U_k$, where $U_{i}=I\otimes I \otimes I ...\otimes O_{i1,i2}..\otimes I$. $I$ is the identical operator on a single qubit and $O_{i1,i2}$ is an arbitrary two-level operator on qubit $i1,i2$. Can such kind of decomposition possible? What's the complexity of it, i.e., $k\sim O(e^n)$? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your precise notion of "simple operator" and how do you define the "accuracy" of the approximation?

Comment: For me, 'simple' means the operator will not work on more than 2 qubits just as the universal gates of quantum circuit model. 'Accuracy' means the distance between the target operator $U$ and the approximated version of it $U'$ is small enough w.r.t. matrix norm. Here I am not interested in an approximation, but a perfect decomposition, i.e., I want $U=U'=U_{1} U_{2}....U_{k}$, where $U_{i}$ is simple and $k~O(e^{n})$ for $U(2^n)$. I hope this can make my problem clear.

Comment: Since the tensor product enlarges the space an operator acts on, I don't understand the question - for an $n$-qubit space, only the tensor product of exactly $n/2$ 2-qubit operator (all on different qubits) will give an operator on $n$-qubit space. I suppose you are seeking for a different decomposition than that into the *tensor product* of "at most $\mathrm{e}^n$ simply operators".

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I mean every simple operator looks like $U_{i}=I \otimes I \otimes...\otimes O_{i1,i2} ...\otimes I$, where $I$ is the identical operator on a single qubit and $O_{i1,i2}$ is a two-level operator on qubit $i1,i2$. So each operator $U_i$ is simple, or local, and the target operator $U$ can be regarded as a successive implementation of all the $U_i$s. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! I don't know the answer, but you should edit this clarification into your question to make it more accessible!

Comment: Cross-posted to math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405194

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such a kind of *exact* decomposition is always possible.  This is shown in [Barenco *et al.*, Elementary gates for quantum computation](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) (Sec. 8, pg. 27 in the arXiv preprint), based on work by [Reck *et al.*](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.58) (which gives a corresponding decomposition where each elementary operation is the identity except for a $2\times 2$ *submatrix*).  The construction given requires $O(n^34^n)$ two-qubit gates.

Comment: Wow: that's a staggering and unexpected complexity ($O(n^34^n)$) given the $O(n^2)$ complexity of the $R Z B^2$ algorithm.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance ??? RZB$^2$??

Comment: Sorry if that was a little obtuse: $RZB^2$ is Reck, Zeilinger, Bernstein, Bertani - the Reck et al algorithm you referenced.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance And what's unexpected about that, then?